# Hotel Reservation Request Booking Paypal PHP

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, paypal

I'm making a website for a small hotel in php. The hotel owners want a reservation system that uses paypal. They want people to see a calendar and choose a date to make a reservation. If the day has vacancy, they want the user to request booking a room. This would then require the hotel owner to accept the purchase.

I have not worked on a project that has this "request to purchase" method of buying with paypal. Is this possible? Does anyone know of an open php system that handles this?

Comment: Adding paypal is generally very simple, you just need to process your transaction, get the amount, plug the paypal api, send some info and according to the response they send, direct the user to a success or fail page. Read the docs on the paypal site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of popular WordPress themes with booking systems built in:

- [HotelPress](http://www.dailywp.com/hotelpress-theme/)
- [HotelBooking](http://templatic.com/app-themes/hotel-booking-wordpress-theme/)

Answer (score 1):

Try php-residence : http://www.hoteldruid.com/en/

PHP, Open Source, but I think the Paypal plugin is a paid for add on.

Comment: yes it requires payment

Answer (score 0):

Sounds fairly straight forwards -
I don't know of an available system in PHP, I'm an ASP guy.

However if you are any good at back-end PHP it wouldn't be a big job to code yourself, might take a few days to a week if youre not used heavy back end.